# what are JPA references

Tags: java, jpa, annotations

I've been learning Java for about 3 months now and have come across the term 'JPA references'.

Could someone give me a really simple explanation of what this means? 
I came across the term whilst working with annotations (i.e @Required, @MaxSize) when working with database fields, but couldn't find a simple explanation on the net which explained it to me.

Also, is it related to JPA Entities, or is this quite different?

Many Thanks in Advance.

Comment: JPA: Java Persistence API.

Comment: I think you might be referring to a term used in the definition of releationships (like `@ManyToOne @JoinColumn(... referencedColumnName="...")` but it's hard to be certain without context - could you add a link and/or quote from a document where you encountered this term?

Comment: @fvu that's correct. It's in the context of relationships with database fields. I don't have a link as it was mentioned on a support ticket '..handle nested entity references including JPA references'.
Which also relates to mapping our fields to the database fields.

Answer (score 1):

it seems that your talking about "jsf" not "jpa". this annotation are use in jsf . JPA is a framwork that used in DATA Acces Layer and you should not mistake it with JSF that used in Presentation Layer.
i really recommended you to read ""Mastering the Java™ Persistence API 2009"" book that publish from ""APRESS". it is easy learning and you can learn it very soon